# The meaning of "It isn't honest"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Jenny got really angry. "**It isn't honest**", she said.
> I didn't listen. I bet all my money on myself to win and then I lost the fight. (I was told to lose the fight)

What does it mean by sentence **"it isn't honest"**?

I think it implies that she can't believe what she's been told or it's somehow unpleasant, Am I right?

Comment: It means that what the fighter was planning to do was not a right and proper way to behave.

Comment: Do you understand what "honest" means?

Comment: @gotube yes it means to tell the truth or someone who always tell the truth

Comment: @MohammadBarbast So what part of "it isn't honest" do you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

The snippet that you've provided is slightly confusing. In the context of a fighting contest, such as a boxing match, with this sort of concern for honesty I'd be expecting that the fighter was intending to throw the bout, to lose on purpose.

A dishonest approach would be to bet all your money on your opponent, and then lose on purpose claiming a much bigger return than the winning prize money. However that doesn't make much sense when he then bets all his money on himself to win.

Comment: I added a point in context: (I was told to lose the fight)

Comment: So here "its not honest" means "you are lying" or  "you are deceiving me" or ...?

Comment: Not honest refers to the overall behaviour. Entering a competition intending to lose when others expect you to try to win is not honest behaviour. I would generally consider this to be deceiving the wider public rather than 'Jenny' but the whole set of actions is still unclear. Who told him to lose? Why is he still betting on himself? Does Jenny expect him to try to win?